# Необычная стилизация слайдера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, slick.js

Подскажите пожайлуста, хотелось бы разобраться как реализован эффект скролла на данном сайте - https://vegaplast.ua/ Как я понимаю это так это так застилен слайдер или может это сторонняя библиотека. Кто то сталкивался?

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/3D-Cube-Page-Transition-Plugin-With-jQuery-cubeTransition-js.html

Comment: больше спасибо!